# How to access each element in a dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a dictionary which contains list as one of the value. I want to access the key and the values in separately. I want to access the elements of the list too individually.

I am trying to plot a decision tree using the final answer that I have. To do so, I have to access each element separately. The final answer that I have is given below. Could anyone help me with how I can access each value separately?

```
tree = {
    "petal_width <= 0.8": [
        "Iris-setosa", 
        {
            "petal_width <= 1.75": [
                {
                    "petal_length <= 4.95": [
                        {
                            "petal_width <= 1.65": [
                                "Iris-versicolor", 
                                "Iris-virginica"
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "petal_width <= 1.55": [
                                "Iris-virginica", 
                                {
                                    "petal_length <= 5.45": [
                                        "Iris-versicolor", 
                                        "Iris-virginica"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "petal_length <= 4.85": [
                        {
                            "sepal_width <= 3.1": [
                                "Iris-virginica", 
                                "Iris-versicolor"
                            ]
                        }, 
                        "Iris-virginica"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

After accessing the elements I want to plot a decision tree in the following format.

[image: https://images.app.goo.gl/twNqgqq6tzMa2Ykj8]

Comment: There aren't any lists in this code.  Did you mean _tuple_ instead of _list_?

Comment: Why not use graphviz or other tool?

Comment: Is there a reason the data is organized this way?  It seems quite confusing.

Comment: I am trying to write the code for a decision tree without using _sklearn_ and _graphviz_. Thanks for the question anyway @Celius Stingher

Comment: For the code that I have written, the answer is coming in this format. I will try to improve the format of answer though. @John Gordon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you have a multi-layer dictionary, where:

**Keys** are strings

**Values** can be:

- dictionaries
- tuples
- strings

Try this code, with separate recursive functions for parsing tuples and dictionaries. I created a function `my_action` with `print` but you can replace it with whatever you want. As you can see, in the function(s) you get also the keys.

```py
def parse_tuple(t):
    tuplen = len(t)
    for i in range(tuplen):
        v = t[i]
        if isinstance(v, tuple):
            parse_tuple(v)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            parse_dictionary(v)
        elif isinstance(v, str):
            my_action(v)
        else:
            print(v.dtype+" is not taken into account !")    

def parse_dictionary(d):
    for k in d:
        my_action(k)
        v = d[k]
        if isinstance(v, list):
            parse_dictionary(d[k])
        #elif isinstance(v, list):
         #   parse_list(v)
        elif isinstance(v, tuple):
            parse_tuple(v)    
        elif isinstance(v, str):
            my_action(v)

def my_action(x):
    print(x)

parse_dictionary(tree)
```

On your input, you obtain this result :

```
petal_width <= 0.8
Iris-setosa
petal_width <= 1.75
petal_length <= 4.95
petal_width <= 1.65
Iris-versicolor
Iris-virginica
petal_width <= 1.55
Iris-virginica
petal_length <= 5.45
Iris-versicolor
Iris-virginica
petal_length <= 4.85
sepal_width <= 3.1
Iris-virginica
Iris-versicolor
Iris-virginica
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how you can access the elements from a list inside a dictionary and also the keys of the dictionary.

```
d = {
    'k1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'k2': [1,2],
    'k3': [1]
    }

for k in d:
  list_pos_k = d[k]
  print(f'key: {k}')
  print(f'elements in list: ')
  for el in list_pos_k:
    print(el)
```

Comment: Using the above lines of code, I am not able to access each element separately as asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a dictionary that has one key and one value. The key is `petal_width <= 0.8` and the value is a tuple.

```py
for key, value in tree.items():
    print("Key: {}\nValue: {}".format(key,value))
```

To get independent elements in a tuple, you call `name_of_the_tuple[0]` and `name_of_the_tuple[1]`, or if you want them both:

```
for item in enumerate(name_of_the_tuple):
    print(item)
```

In your case, it would be:

```py
for key, value in tree.items():
    print("Key: {}\nFirst Value: {}\nSecond Value: {}".format(key,value[0],value[1]))
```

Now, the ugly part is that you must start over, because `value1` is also a dictionary with only one key and one value that is a tuple. Code it would look like that:

```
for key, value in tree.items():
    print("Key: {}\nFirst Value: {}\nSecond Value: {}".format(key,value[0],value[1]))
    for key1, value1 in value[1].items():
        print("Key: {}\nThird Value: {}\nFourth Value: {}".format(key1,value1[0],value1[1]))
```

...and so on, until you unpack all dictionaries and tuples.

Comment: Yes, it can be done line by line but I dont want to do it individually, I want to write something that can help me to access each element individually without having to access each key value seperately. Thanks for your explanation anyway.